# How to load excel / pdf server url in WKWebView Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I wanted to load the excel sheet url/pdf url (document url) in WKWebView. As I am trying to open that url from browser then it directly downloads that document. So I am confused whether 1] I have to directly load the url into WKWebView or 2] first download those files and then load that local path in WKWebView.

If I go with the 2nd option then will my document download every time? 
Following is the code which I have tried but it shows nothing

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class OpenReportsFullScreenVC: UIViewController,WKUIDelegate {

    var webView : WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //first way :- webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://ipaddress/projects/ourivf/newourivf/assets/uploads/patient_image/attorney_details - Copy.xls")!))
        // second way
        let filePathURLData =  "http://ipaddress/projects/ourivf/newourivf/assets/uploads/patient_image/attorney_details - Copy.xls"
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePathURLData )
        webView.loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: fileURL)

        }

    override func loadView() {
        //initialise webview
        let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you can do both ways. If you choose path #2, then the document will be downloaded every time. You would have to implement some sort of cache mechanism. Your code does not show anything, because your URL does not seems to work.

Comment: thanks for ur valuable reply. Actually its local url and working fine on local server.. but it directly downloading the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this code

```
import UIKit

import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , **WKNavigationDelegate**{

    var webView : WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        let myBlog = "your URl"  
        let url = NSURL(string: myBlog)!
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)

        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(request as URLRequest)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: webView)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

File path cannot have blank characters like in your example.